# problem with combination of \foreach loops in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, loops

I have a problem regarding the plot of multiple lines with a defined shift. There are several y-values and I don't want to copy every command, so I tried a for loop for the `y index` and the `shift`.

With the current code I get a plot of all data which is shifted.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{
    pgfplots,
    pgfplotstable,
    filecontents
}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{test.txt}
    0   0.87    0.21    0.64    0.49    0.40    0.94
    1   0.67    0.74    0.86    0.19    0.86    0.83
    2   0.87    0.34    0.49    0.32    0.59    0.92
    3   0.25    0.09    0.76    0.35    0.27    0.29
    4   0.27    0.52    0.91    0.64    0.67    0.46
    5   0.34    0.44    0.45    0.56    0.51    0.67
\end{filecontents}

\def\xmin{0}
\def\xmax{5}
\def\ymin{0}
\def\ymax{6}
\def\shift{1}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \begin{axis}[
            ymin=\ymin,
            ymax=\ymax,
            xmin=\xmin,
            xmax=\xmax,
            restrict y to domain=\xmin:\xmax,
            restrict y to domain=\ymin:\ymax,
            enlargelimits=0.1
            ]           
            \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,1,...,5}{
                \foreach \i in {1,2,...,6}{
                    \addplot[
                    color=black,
                    smooth,
                    shift={(axis direction cs:0,#1*\shift)},
                    ]
                    table[
                    x index=0, 
                    y index=\i,
                    ]{test.txt};
                }
            }       
        \end{axis}  
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: testpic]

Is there a way to plot each line once and shifted to each other in a for loop?

**EDIT:**

For clearification: I want to plot each line individually with a certain shift.

[image: goal]

Comment: Could you please rephrase the problem? The plot does change if you redefine `\shift` to a different value and/or if you change the range of `\i` in the inner loop. What precisely is wrong with the current behavior?

Comment: Let's assume, I have 8 different plots. I want to plot these curves each individually (different ```\i```) with an increasing shift (```(\i+1)*\shift```).

Comment: Can't you just use one loop, i.e. not two loops, via `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` and then `shift={(axis direction cs:0,#1*\shift)}` along with `y index=#1`?

Comment: That would be possible, but the problem is, that the ```y index``` is one value higher than the ```shift parameter```. Is there a way to define the parameter like ```#1+1```?

Comment: `shift={(axis direction cs:0,{(1+#1)*\shift})}` or add another shift (they accumulate).

Answer (score 0):

While looking at the manual of PgfPlots, I found a solution for the problem:

```
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \i/\j in {0/1,1/2,2/3,3/4,4/5,5/6}{
    \edef\temp{
        \noexpand
        \addplot[
        color=black,
        smooth,
        shift={(axis direction cs:0,\i*\shift)},
        ]
        table[
        x index=0, 
        y index=\j,
        ]{test.txt};
    }\temp
}
```

Here you have to enter each index individually, which can be a bit cumbersome with larger amounts of data. So if someone knows a 'simpler' solution, let me know.

Comment: you can accept own answer. Unfortunately you show only code snippet, so it is hard to test it and see how it works ...